# JSOUP doesn't work on a certain website

Tags: java, jsoup

I wrote a method to analyze a website - to find all the unique links in it and calculate the size (in bytes) of all the images. In case of some websites, it works, but with some (`"https://www.nasa.gov"`) it doesn't. Could someone kind please give a hint on what is the reason?

```
/**
 * @param url - url to the page to be parsed
 * @return - a hashset of unique links found in the page
 * @throws IOException - whan a problem with the connection occurs
 */
private static HashSet<String> AnalyzeUrl(String url) throws IOException
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    HashSet<String> uniqueImages = new HashSet<>();
    HashSet<String> uniqueLinks = new HashSet<>();

    // Get unique images
    Elements images = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
    for (Element image : images)
        uniqueImages.add(image.attr("abs:src"));

    // Get unique links
    Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
    for (Element link : links)
        uniqueLinks.add(link.attr("abs:href"));

    // Get total size of images
    int totalSize = 0;
    for (String imageUrl : uniqueImages)
        totalSize += Jsoup.connect(imageUrl).ignoreContentType(true).execute().bodyAsBytes().length;

    // Show information
    String information = "Unique images found: " + uniqueImages.size() + "\n" +
                         "Total size of images: " + totalSize + " bytes \n" +
                         "Unique links found: " + uniqueLinks.size() + "\n";

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, information, ButtonType.OK);
    alert.showAndWait();

    return uniqueLinks;
}
```

Comment: Check out the source code : There are no `img` nor `a` tags in the source. They are generated by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be caused by how the redirect is done. If the website uses javascript for this, the connection won't get redirected since JSOUP doesn't support javascript.
You need to check the website and provide more information, hope it helps.